# Does serialization of objects with same class but different packages cause an errors in Axon?

Tags: gradle, axon

I read a blog post and there was a sentence like this
*"**In Axon, there are constraints that require the package structure of the Event classes to be identical.
So even the same class, if the package is different, an error can occur."***

And for this reason, he recommends using a multi-module structure.

is that true? I'm looking at the references and trying to find something like this, but I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This point is indeed true, @YongD.
Axon Framework, when serializing any of your objects, will store the serialized format and the type. The serialized format that's stored most often is a `byte[]` of either XML or JSON. Which of the two depends on whether you have configured the `XStreamSerializer` or the `JacksonSerializer`.

So next to the serialized data, we have the type. The type, by default, would be the fully qualified class name and an optional revision number. Without the fully qualified class name, the serializer wouldn't know how to deserialize your data back into the required format. The package name is part of the FQCN, having different package names for conceptually the same class might cause issues upon deserialization.

This is why in sample projects provided by AxonIQ, you will always see *all* the messages belong to a `core-api` or `api` package or module. Already having this separation will allow for easier extraction of services into microservices at a later stage.